# Where did the mandatory "Feature-request" tag come from?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Why am I forced to use the "feature-request" tag when I am not requesting a feature? This notification showed up for me today when editing an existing question, and when creating this new question.

Is there any way to avoid it, other than entering this usually-incorrect tag? Meta is for meta-discussion, not just feature-requests, correct?

[except, for this question, it IS a feature request. hrm.]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Well, the `status-completed` tag was added, so I guess this is fixed.

Comment: yep. but no answer, so nothing I can accept. Drive-by solution! I'm assuming the Geoff Dalgas fixed it, as he removed the "feature-request" tag and added "status-completed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required tags were updated to include "bug discussion support feature-request"

[image: The required tags were updated to include "bug discussion support feature-request"]